# Texmaker doesn't export to html (OS X El Capitan)

Tags: texmaker, tex4ht, mac, htlatex

After upgrading to El Capitan I fixed the configuration and it is working fine. But it does not export to html with the tex4ht option. It yields the following output:

```
"/Library/TeX/texbin/htlatex" "/Users/Me/Documents/test.tex" " " " " " " -interaction=nonstopmode
/Library/TeX/texbin/htlatex: line 2: latex: command not found /Library/TeX/texbin/htlatex: line 3: latex: command not found /Library/TeX/texbin/htlatex: line 4: latex: command not found /Library/TeX/texbin/htlatex: line 5: tex4ht: command not found /Library/TeX/texbin/htlatex: line 6: t4ht: command not found
Process exited with error(s)
```

I could run htlatex through the command line, so the problem seems to be with TexMaker.

Also updated to texmaker 4.5, and now the error message is:

```
--- warning --- Can't find/open file `path/file.dvi' --- error --- Can't find/open file `path/file.dvi'
--- warning --- Can't find/open file `path/file.lg'
```

I also tried running LaTeX first in order to create the dvi file, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue using texmaker 4.4.1, but it went away after I updated to 4.5.  It looks like 4.5 was only just released on Oct 29.

Comment: If this is the general solution, it will most likely become obsolete in the future. As such, would it be a good idea to close this question later?

Comment: Thanks, but I updated to 4.5 and still have problems. Will update the post with more information.

Comment: Did you install MacTeX-2015? Are you able to typeset in TeXmaker?